# Какой знак нужен перед "они"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Посмотри вон на них **они** же такие ничтожные, что даже подойти боятся.*

Answer (score 1):

Двоеточие, необходимое для бессоюзной связи и характеристики образа этих людей.

**Важно**: "них" следует убрать и заменить на "этих людей" либо другое аналогичное сочетание, иначе получается повтор однокоренных ("них" — форма Р.п личного местоимения "они")

Comment: Какая это тавтология? У вас если однокоренные слова стоят рядом, это всегда тавтология? Даже если в разных основах?

И второе: тавтология что, всегда зло? Да ничуть не бывало.

Comment: Вы учителю русского языка или, не дай Бог, комисси скажите, что в тавтологии ничего плохого нет. Разные грамматические основы в некоторой степени могут быть преобразованы в предложения, в которых от тавтологии уже никак не отвертеться: "Посмотри на них. **Они** такие ничтожные". Масло масляное, что называется.

Comment: Надеюсь, что я сейчас не с учителем русского языка беседую. Не дай бог!

Подобных фраз везде навалом, в том числе и у признанных стилистов. Неужто не встречали? Читайте больше.

Comment: О речевой избыточности https://studfiles.net/preview/1608875/page:15/

Comment: @Бот  Ваш ответ в основном верен, поэтому я отмечаю его положительным знаком, но есть неточности в оформлении.

Answer (score 1):

*(1) Посмотри **вон на тех:** (2) они же такие ничтожные, (3)что даже подойти боятся.*

1) Двоеточие ставится в сложном предложении и обозначает **пояснительные** отношения между предложением 1 и предложениями 2 и 3.

Смысл такой: *Посмотри вон на тех, и ты увидишь...*

2) В заданном предложении повторяется местоимение: ***они, на них,*** поэтому требуется замена.

**Примечание:** При редактировании предложения желательно приводить полученный вариант полностью.